# What in the definition of a pentagon prevents three vertices on the same edge

Tags: geometry

The definition of a Pentagon says (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagon) "five-sided polygon" but let ABCD be a square and E the middle of AB. Is AEBCD a pentagon?
What in the definition of a pentagon "prevents" this from happening? And more generally hexagons, etc ...

Does "five-sided" does not work if the side defined by AE is the same as the one by EB?

Comment: Context matters. Sometimes authors want this to be a pentagon, sometimes not. When there's any doubt, it's the author's job to make their meaning clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the shape you describe is considered a pentagon then it can, by extension be described as an $n$-gon (for $n>5$) by simply adding additional points on the line segment.

So, to avoid this, there is an assumption when we say shape $X$ is an $n$-gon that it has $n$ angles, none of which are equal to $\pi$.

There is nothing wrong with describing your shape as a pentagon, but many would consider it a trivial case.

Comment: *"There is nothing wrong with describing your shape as a pentagon, but many would consider it a trivial case."* It's perhaps more appropriate to call OP's shape a "degenerate" pentagon, rather than a "trivial" one.

Comment: Thanks @Blue - you are correct. "Degenerate" is a better phrase in this instance.